# Value of a that Minimizes $\mathbb{E}([aX-\frac{1}{a}]^2)$

Tags: probability

> Suppose X is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance
>   $\sigma^{2}$.
>
> For what value of a, where a > 0, is $\mathbb{E}([aX-\frac{1}{a}]^2)$
>   minimized?

Comment: Can you use $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ to make a first attempt at an answer? Note that $f(x)$ is the probability density function of the random variable $X$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further I cannot follow the E[g(x)] part?

Comment: @Ritz Sorry but this is offtopic.

Comment: Hint: $E((aX-1/a)^2)=E(X^2)a^2-2E(X)+1/a^2$. Surely you can minimize some function $a\mapsto ba^2+c+1/a^2$ on $a>0$?

Comment: @Did It would lead to the same thing you mentioned but with an intermediate step. I agree that your method is quicker.

Comment: Except there's no mention of a pdf in the question @Ritz.

Comment: @Ritz This would 1. mask the relevant computation, 2. force to assume that X has a PDF.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without thinking too much - brute force method:

$$g(a) \triangleq E\left[\left(aX - \frac {1} {a}\right)^2\right] 
= a^2E[X^2] - 2E[X] + \frac {1} {a^2} = (\sigma^2+\mu^2)a^2 - 2\mu + \frac {1} {a^2} $$

Differentiating with respect to $a$, we have
$$ \frac {\partial g(a)} {\partial a} = 2(\sigma^2+\mu^2)a - \frac {2} {a^3}
= \frac {2} {a^3}[(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)a^4 - 1]$$

Note
$$ (\sigma^2 + \mu^2)a^4 - 1 
\begin{cases} 
> 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a < -\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
= 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a = -\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
< 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle -\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}} < a <
\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}   \\
= 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a = \frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
> 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a > \frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Therefore
$$\frac {\partial g(a)} {\partial a} 
\begin{cases} 
< 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a < -\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
= 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a = -\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
> 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle -\frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}} < a < 0 \\
< 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle 0 < a < \frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}\\
= 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a = \frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
> 0 & \text{if} & 
\displaystyle a > \frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}  \\
\end{cases}$$

So $g$ has two local minima at $\displaystyle\pm \frac {1} {(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^{1/4}}$, and you can check they are both the global minima. Since you restrict $a > 0$ (just seen it), you take the positive one.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:
$$
\mathrm{E}[(aX-\tfrac1a)^2]=a^2(\sigma^2+\mu^2)+\tfrac{1}{a^2}-2\mu.
$$
Now minimize this function with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Showing as much work as OP shows in the question:

$a = \begin{cases}
    \infty ,& \mu = \sigma = 0 \\
    1/\sqrt{|\mu|} ,& \mu \neq 0, \sigma = 0 \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\mu^2 + \sigma^2}} ,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$.